# Discord.js - Logging channel deletes gives error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying make my discord.js bot log when people create, and delete channels using the audit logs. I have the create logging down, but the delete part is giving me an error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". I don't know why it won't work.

My channel delete logging code:

```
bot.on("channelDelete", async() => {
    var channeldeleteauditlogs = await bot.guilds.find(g => g.id === '621810400924794890').fetchAuditLogs({
        type: 11
    });

    let entry = channeldeleteauditlogs.entries.first();
    var channeldeletelog = fs.readFileSync('channeldeletelog.txt', 'utf-8');
    var channeldeletelog2 = fs.writeFileSync('channeldeletelog.txt', '\nTime - ' + entry.createdAt.toUTCString() + ' | Channel - ' + entry.target.name + ' | User - ' + entry.executor.username + ' (' + entry.executor.id + ')' + channeldeletelog);

    console.log(entry.executor.username + " deleted a channel");
});
```

My (Successful) channel create logging code:

```
bot.on("channelCreate", async() => {
    let channelcreateauditlogs = await bot.guilds.find(g => g.id === '621810400924794890').fetchAuditLogs({
        type: 10
    });

    let entry = channelcreateauditlogs.entries.first();
    var channelcreatelog = fs.readFileSync('channelcreatelog.txt', 'utf-8');
    var channelcreatelog2 = fs.writeFileSync('channelcreatelog.txt', '\nTime - ' + entry.createdAt.toUTCString() + ' | Channel - ' + entry.target.name + ' (' + entry.target.id + ') | User - ' + entry.executor.username + ' (' + entry.executor.id + ')' + channelcreatelog);

    console.log(entry.executor.username + " created a channel");
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `channel` parameter that comes with the `channelDelete` event.

```
bot.on("channelDelete", async (channel) => {
    console.log(channel.name)
```

Comment: or to access your audit logs directly, you can also use the 'changes' property from your 'entries' variable and access the channel name with `entries.changes[0].old`